# Convert UTC milliseconds to browser's time using moment.local() and moment.toDate() is not accurate

Tags: javascript, momentjs

```
var utcMilliSeconds = 1486116995814;
// UTC time:03/02/2017 10:16:35 (From epoch Converter)
// IST time:03/02/2017, 15:46:35 (From epoch converter) 

moment.utc(1486116995814).local().format("DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:ss"); //IST time:03/02/2017 15:02:35  but it's wrong

moment.utc(1486116995814).toDate(); //Fri Feb 03 2017 15:46:35 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

`toDate()` giving correct time but i don't want to use `toDate()` since JavaScript date is not flexible for formatting.

What is the wrong with `moment.local()`, why it's not giving the accurate time, is there any easy way converting UTC millis to browser's time without using any other libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using uppercase `MM` instead of lowercase `mm` for formatting minutes. See [formatting docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/). `MM` stands for months, while `mm` stands for minutes.

Here a working example:

```js
var s = moment.utc(1486116995814).local().format("DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss");
console.log(s);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, its my bad. using moment will work for sure all the time zones with day light savings it won't create any problem?. could you please confirm?

Comment: I confirm that the code shared will work without problem regardless the timezone. Moment can handle time conversion between UTC and local time, if you need to convert between timezones you can use [moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/)

Answer (score 0):

I tried this way and work properly

```
var timeInUTCMiliSecond = 1641367170421
let ConvertedTime = moment.unix(timeInUTCMiliSecond / 1000).format("hh:mm")
consol.log(ConvertedTime)
```

Or any Format you want

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.